# How to run lilypond-book in LaTeX?

Tags: compiling, lilypond

Lilypond, as you might know, is a computer program and file format for music engraving. I've wanted to include music in LaTeX PDF documents using `lilypond-book` (A Lilypond executable file), but I don't really understand how. This might be a silly question; I am a novice at these things. Can you please clearly inform me on how to use `lilypond-book`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the section on this in the Lilypond documentation?

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/usage/lilypond_002dbook

I personally didn't like this automated process, because it creates a bunch of auxiliary files, but anyway...

When I needed to create a document with text and musical examples, I produced the examples in Lilypond (PDF files with a cropped fragment of music) and added them in LaTeX files as figures.